# Where to store custom tagging data associated with a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, database, tags

My application allows users to add tags to an image (similar to facebook). Each tag can consist of up to 8 attributes and there is currently no limit on the amount of tags a user can add.

At the moment, tag information is stored across 3 post meta key/value pairs. Each post meta value is serialized before storing.

We're approaching a rewrite of this functionality and I wanted to ask for some advice on the best approach to storing tag data.

IMO there are two approaches:

1. post meta key/value for each tag/attribute (this has the potential to create a huge dataset - `n` tags times 8 attributes)
2. A new table just for tags

Both approaches would avoid storing serialized data, which I think is what I need to achieve.

Which is the better approach?
Is a third option possibly even more feasible?

Answer (score 2):

Avoid serialized whenever you can. It is slow to read and you cannot really search for it.

Use custom tables – more than one:

1. One for the relationship between users, tags and images: `user_id`, `tag_id` and `image_id`.
2. One for tag meta data, your attributes, if I understand that right: `tag_id`, `meta_1`, `meta_2` …

Now you can look up for each attachment ID if there is an entry for the user, and then look up the meta data from the meta table.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play around with a sample schema based on your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a custom table or post meta to store the tag information you will probably find a simpler solution if you investigate the Custom Taxonomy support within WordPress.

You can register one (or more) custom taxonomies against the attachment post type.

The following Codex pages are a good place to start:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies

You may also find inspiration in existing WordPress plugins which provide similar functionality such as http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/matts-community-tags/trunk

Comment: I've had a play around with taxonomies and how I think it could work for tags with the application and I've got a couple of potential approaches. Feedback would be much appreciated. http://pastebin.com/79tnV1Ev

Comment: @Oldie your pastebin link doesn't work for me

Comment: I've created a gist - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dc2b058d7a36ae57c240

Comment: So looking at this the first approach is going to work more successfully because the second approach makes the data really hard to query using the WordPress APIs.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I've created a POC based around using custom taxonomies. Initial implementation looked very promising. However, I have noticed a potential issue. For example, tag_t1 can include the term 'Accessories'. The user may wish to add more than 1 look tag with the term 'Accessories' under the tag_t1 taxonomy (Accessories > belt, Accessories > glasses). From what I can see, it doesn't seem to be possible to add the same term more than once for a taxonomy. Can you confirm? Thanks.